# unable to load rspec generator in rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

i am working on rails 2.3.5 where i want to us `Rspec` for testing purpose. I have installed rspec gem but not able to list rspec in generator's list. I am referring https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec", "~> 1.3"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 1.3"
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put that content? Did you set up Bundler correctly?

Comment: @Ryan =>  bundler is working fine and I am able to install all the gems with bundler. I have put the above content in a Gemfile.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks Ryan. It turns out I had to include other gems as well to run the rspec. I added   gem "rspec", "~> 1.3"
  gem "rspec-core"
  gem "rspec-expectations"
  gem "rspec-mocks"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 1.3"
  gem "shoulda"
now its working fine.

Comment: I made it work with the generator. Added spec folder and manually added the spec_helper file and added it to the spec file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on rails 2.3.5 you will have to install two plugins :

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec.git -r 'refs/tags/1.2.9'
```

and

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails.git -r 'refs/tags/1.2.9'
```

Then check the rspec generate list

```
ruby script/generate rspec
```

Please check https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails for further details.

Hope this helps.